# AppleScript application support: 'duplicate' command fails

Tags: command, applescript, duplicates

I am trying to support the 'duplicate' command. It works fine for duplicating the top class:

```
tell application "SpellAnalysis" to duplicate level 1
```

This, however, crashes:

```
tell application "SpellAnalysis" to duplicate (get unit 1 of (get level 1))
```

I have provided index specifiers for both classes, where the outer container for  'unit' is 'level'. Oddly, I can specify a property of the unit class like this:

```
tell application "SpellAnalysis" to (get general rule of unit 1 of (get level 1))
```

The culprit seems to be that the 'objectsByEvaluatingSpecifier' always returns a null value when used within NSCloneCommand subclass, as well as the unit class' objectSpecifier method, where its needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to support AppleScript 'duplicate' command. Although the normal way to support the command is by sub-classing 'NSCloneCommand', with this method, your direct parameter results in a specifier that specifies the containing object and not the direct object--as a special provision of the 'NSCloneCommand'. I suppose this is meant to facilitate the case when you would be duplicating an object belonging to a document, where the document class provides the means for creating new constituent objects. Unfortunately, in my case, my constituent objects take part in their own duplication and need to know their specifiers to do so. The solution was to support the 'duplicate' command by the optional technique of creating a custom 'duplicate' command within my application's suite that entailed subclassing the more general 'NSScriptCommand'. This alternative avoids any redirection of the specifier returned from the 'directParameter' method of the 'NSScriptCommand' class. I was able to work from there to derive all the child class-objects for cloning.

Comment: Thanks a million--there aren't many folks around that know how to do this stuff.